# Align multiple cell items on more than one row in a table

Tags: html, css

I have the following.

[image]

it more or less represents this in pseudo

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Depart Base</td>
        <td>*time box*</td>
        <td>*time box*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mode of Transport</td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox'>
            <label>Dedicated ambulance</label>
            <input type='checkbox'>
            <label>AIR</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox'>
            <label>Other ambulance</label>
            <input type='checkbox'>
            <label>Taxi</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type='checkbox'>
            <label>RRV</label>
            <input type='checkbox'>
            <label>Other</label>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But as you can see the radio buttons are not aligned.

This was also done with a inhouse form creator(which is not going to change)

How can I space or align the items in the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your label an `inline-block` element and give it a width:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
  /*or width of your largest label*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Depart Base</td>
    <td>*time box*</td>
    <td>*time box*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mode of Transport</td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>Dedicated ambulance</label>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>AIR</label>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>Other ambulance</label>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>Taxi</label>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>RRV</label>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>Other</label>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard advice is don't use tables for layout. Use them for tabular data. But if you're stuck using that chunk of code, you can use this CSS:

```css
label:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Depart Base</td>
    <td>*time box*</td>
    <td>*time box*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mode of Transport</td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>Dedicated ambulance</label>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>AIR</label>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>Other ambulance</label>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>Taxi</label>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>RRV</label>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <label>Other</label>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Cant. has to be in the structure as I presented it. cant ad extra cell. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

If you can’t change the markup, then your only chance is to give the first label in every cell a “large enough” width, something like this:

```
td label:nth-of-type(1) { display:inline-block; width:9.5em; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ao2rqtnc/1/

A width of `9.5em` seems about to work (with default font applied), but depending on this and other factors it might need more.

Answer (score 1):

This is supposing that your markup cannot be changed, and that you would always have two checkboxes with two labels.

This will fill the cell to it's maximum width, if your table is wider it will obviously look a lot better:

```css
table td input {
  width: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
table td label {
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Depart Base</td>
    <td>*time box*</td>
    <td>*time box*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mode of Transport</td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <label>Dedicated ambulance</label>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <label>AIR</label>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <label>Other ambulance</label>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <label>Taxi</label>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <label>RRV</label>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <label>Other</label>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```